# Is there a Matlab loop equivalent to python's "for in" loop?

Tags: matlab

Is there a matlab equivalent of the "for in" loop in python?

For instance in python, I can iterate through items of a list using the following code:

```
for c_value in C_VALUES:
```

Comment: Be aware: iteration is usually not "the Matlab way to do it".  Most uses of iteration in other languages (like Python) are more elegantly and efficiently expressed in Matlab as matrix operations.

Comment: @RobertCooper Thats true only regarding arrays and matrices. If I had 10 images or different sizes, and had to do the same operation on each of them, I would like to loop in the for _ in list format.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In MATLAB, `for` iterates over the columns of a matrix.  Pretty much the same as your example, if `C_VALUES` were a row.

```
for val = row_vec
    #% stuff in the loop
end
```

is the MATLAB syntax.  `val` will take on the values of `row_vec` as it iterates.  The syntax you will often see (but isn't strictly necessary) is

```
for ii = 1:length(values)
    val = values(ii);
    #% stuff in the loop using val
end
```

Here, `1:length(values)` creates a row vector `[1 2 3 ...]`, and `ii` can be used to index into `values`.

(Note: `i` is another common choice, but as soon as you use `i` in this type of context where it is assigned a value, you don't get to use it in the imaginary number sense anymore).

Answer (score 3):

Please try the following code.

```
 vs = [1 12 123 1234];
    for v = vs
        disp(v)
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on @tmpearce 's answer, a little trick I've found is to use:

```
for i = values(:)'
    #% i iterates through each element of 'values'
end
```

The colon operator ensures the array is a column vector, then transposing it gives you a row vector.